# Proving a function is continuous through differentiability

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I have the following function $f_n (x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$. I want to prove this is continuously differentiable. The method I have used seems like a bit of a shortcut but I was wondering if it was still valid.

I just computed the derivative $f_n'(x)$ and then showed that this functions derivative is defined over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, by computing the second derivative.

Is this valid? Or do I need to prove continuity of the first derivative through a more standard method?

Comment: If you can differentiate a function it's probably differentiable, yes.

Comment: What you did effectively is use the properties of differentiable functions, namely that certain operations with differentiable functions yield differentiable functions. It is correct if you take care of all subtleties such as the differentiability of the resulting function when it is made of square roots, logarithms, etc at the points where these component functions are not differentiable or not defined, but most of the time, these issues are solved by looking at the domain where the computed derivative is defined like you did. I think this process can be made rigurous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid to prove that a function is continuous by actually proving that it is differentiable.

However, it seems more natural for me to see that$$f_n'(x)=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1/n^2}}$$and to say that this function is continuous since it is the quotient of two continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

A function which is differentiable is continuous, $f_n$ is differentiable (continuous) since it is a composition of differentiable (continuous) functions $g_n(x)=x^2+{1\over n^2}$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ (defined on $(0,+\infty)$.